# cbind within a conditional ifelse statement

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have several data frames that are generated by a script, and sometimes they are empty. At the end of my procedure I would like to use `cbind` to put all of the data frames together, however this of course fails if the data frame is "empty."

```
df1 <- structure(list(id1 = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A"), 
                      val1 = c(4,2, 1, 5, 3, 4), 
                      id2 = c("C", "B", "C", "C", "B", NA), 
                      val2 = c(2, 3, 2, 2, 3, NA)), 
                 row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

df2 <- structure(list(), names = character(0), 
                 row.names = integer(0), 
                 class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

df3 <- structure(list(id3 = c("X", "X", "X", "Y", "Y", "Y"), 
                      val3 = c(8, 10, 11, 9, 22, 1)), 
                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

I have tried to do this with a nested `ifelse` statement. For example:

```
df_new <- ifelse(nrow(df1)==0, cbind(df2, df3),
                 ifelse(nrow(df2)==0, cbind(df1, df3), 
                        cbind(df1, df2, df3)))
```

However, this just returns the first column of `df1` as a list... Is there a better way to achieve this? Or is there something about `ifelse` or `cbind` that I'm not understanding? Thank you in advance!

Comment: When they are not empty, do they all have the same number of rows?

Comment: @zx8754 They will have the same row number when not empty.

Comment: try `dfList <- list(df1, df2, df3); dfList <- dfList[sapply(dfList, \(x) nrow(x)) > 0L]; do.call(what = "cbind", args = dfList)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put your `data.frame`s in a list, remove the empty elements (`length == 0`), and then use `cbind` in a `do.call` function.

```r
l <- list(df1, df2, df3)
do.call("cbind", l[lengths(l) > 0])

#   id1 val1  id2 val2 id3 val3
# 1   A    4    C    2   X    8
# 2   A    2    B    3   X   10
# 3   B    1    C    2   X   11
# 4   B    5    C    2   Y    9
# 5   A    3    B    3   Y   22
# 6   A    4 <NA>   NA   Y    1
```

If you prefer `dplyr` functions, you can use `dplyr::bind_cols`:

```r
dplyr::bind_cols(l[lengths(l) > 0])
```

Also `purrr` has a convenient function that you can use to remove empty elements, `compact`:

```r
dplyr::bind_cols(purrr::compact(l))
```

Comment: Simple and fast! Thank you so much for the quick response. That's two great answers from you today!

Answer (score 1):

You have a good solution to your problem from @Mael.  You should accept that answer.

I'm adding this to explain what went wrong with your attempt:

The problem is that you used the `ifelse()` function, instead of the `if ... else ...` statement.

`ifelse(cond, a, b)` is designed to select a single value from `a` or `b`, depending on the value of `cond`.  It assumes `cond`, `a` and `b` are vectors, and returns a vector of the same length as `cond`.

`if (cond) a else b` is what you should have used.  It assumes `cond` is a single value (generally logical, but numerical also works), and selects all of `a` or all of `b`.  No assumptions are made about `a` and `b` except that the one you select exists.

So this code would do what you intended:

```
df_new <- if (nrow(df1)==0) cbind(df2, df3) else
            if (nrow(df2)==0) cbind(df1, df3) else
              cbind(df1, df2, df3)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Very concise and explains where I was going wrong. Accepted the answer from @Mael. Wouldn't let me accept until some time had passed and then I got distracted. Thanks again! Cheers.